# Why can't I see the leaves of a tree through a transparent object?

Tags: particles, eevee-render-engine, transparency, glass

I created a transparent glass object and I am able to see every mesh with the exception of leaves. The tree in the picture includes hair particles on a vertex group with a png image of a branch. You can see in the image how the trunk appears but not the leaves.

[image: Leave picture material settings]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Eevee?

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that I can see the leaves using Cycles. is there anyway of seeing the leaves on Eevee?

Comment: Did you change the blend mode of your transparent material to "alpha-blend" or "alpha-hashed"?

Comment: Same results using alpha-blend.

Comment: None of the blend modes make the leaves visible.

Comment: Do the leaves have transparency themselves? Sometimes eevee doesn't like transparency through transparency.

Comment: I believe the leaves are causing the problem. No, the leaves have the Screen Space Refraction unchecked.

Comment: https://cgcookie.com/articles/blender-cycles-vs-eevee-15-limitations-of-real-time-rendering